# Kerberos issue on Spark when in cluster (YARN) mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

I am using Spark with Kerberos authentication.

I can run my code using `spark-shell` fine and I can also use `spark-submit` in local mode (e.g. `—master local[16]`). Both function as expected.

local mode -

```
spark-submit --class "graphx_sp" --master local[16] --driver-memory 20G target/scala-2.10/graphx_sp_2.10-1.0.jar
```

I am now progressing to run in cluster mode using YARN.

From [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/sg_spark_auth.html) I can see that you need to specify the location of the `keytab` and specify the `principal`. Thus:

```
spark-submit --class "graphx_sp" --master yarn  --keytab /path/to/keytab --principal login_node  --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 13G --total-executor-cores 32 target/scala-2.10/graphx_sp_2.10-1.0.jar
```

However, this returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Login failure for login_node from keytab /path/to/keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:987)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:564)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:897)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:760)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:978)
    ... 4 more
```

Before I run using spark-shell or on local mode in spark-submit I do the following kerberos setup:

```
kinit -k -t ~/keytab -r 7d `whoami`
```

Clearly, this setup is not extending to the YARN setup. How do I fix the Kerberos issue with YARN in cluster mode? Is this something which must be in my /src/main/scala/graphx_sp.scala file?

### Update

By running `kinit -V -k -t ~/keytab -r 7d`whoami in verbose mode I was able to see the prinicpal was in the form `user@node`.

I updated this, checked the location of the `keytab` and things passed through this checkpoint succesfully:

```
INFO security.UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user user@login_node using keytab file /path/to/keytab
```

However, it then fails post this with:

```
client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Authentication required
```

I have checked the permissions on the keytab and the read permissions are correct. It has been suggested that the next possibility is a corrupt keytab

Comment: Check the actual values you used for these:                                                  --keytab /path/to/keytab                                                                                   --principal login_node

Comment: Thanks @THeron. How would I check these values? I know the keytab path is correct. I presumed the contents were correct as I was able to login. I set the principal as the node I log in on and issue this command from.

Comment: You should first try to validate the keytab by pulling a Kerberos ticket using it, as a one-off test.

Comment: Ok. Is that not what kinit does? So, `kinit -k -t ~/keytab -r 7d `whoami`` would fail if the keytab could not be validated?

Comment: I've been meaning to make an instruction on this and post it to the web.  I'll send you a link.

Comment: The syntax for a "principal" should be `user@REALM`, and `kinit` is doing you a favor by appending the default Realm. But Hadoop will not. So run a `klist -k /path/to/keytab` to check what is the **exact** principal that your keytab relates to. And use that one in your Spark command line.

Comment: Samson, you're 100% right. I realised this when I ran `kinit` in verbose mode. It output the principal then and it was in the format `user@REALM`. However, the error unfortunately persists. I shall update the question

Comment: Not familiar with using Kerberos on Spark, but it turns out to be an access control exception.  Perhaps, there should be some acls included too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out that the `Authentication 
required` error happens, when the application tries to read from HDFS. 
Scala was doing lazy evaluation, so it didn't fail, until it started 
processing the file. This read from HDFS line: 
`webhdfs://name:50070`.

Since, WEBHDFS defines a public HTTP REST API to permit access, I 
thought it was using `acls`, but enabling `ui.view.acls` didn't fix the 
issue. Adding `--conf 
spark.yarn.access.namenodes=webhdfs://name:50070` fixed the 
problem. This provides comma-separated list of secure HDFS namenodes, 
which the Spark application is going to access. Spark acquires the 
security tokens for each of the namenodes so that the application can 
access those remote HDFS clusters. This fixed the authentication 
required error.

Alternatively, direct access to HDFS `hdfs://file` works and authenticates using Kerberos, with principal and keytab being passed during `spark-submit`.

Comment: Alternatively, direct access to HDFS hdfs://file works and authenticates using Kerberos, with principal and keytab being passed during spark-submit. What does this mean